# Unable to save jenkins system configuration, how to fix that?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, eks

I am running jenkins in eks cluster.
Till yesterday it worked, but today when I want to change any configuration in the jenkins system configuration page, it is not saving anything and page is also not loading properly.

Below is the log I got from the jenkins pod.
Log file [github link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uday1kiran/logs/master/eks/jenkins/jenkins-5d696c8976-ck5g7.log)

I tried to paste here but character limit exceeded.

Could you please suggest what need to be fixed?

Comment: Check file permissions. See what user jenkins runs as, then check if the dirs and files indeed grant access to said user.

Comment: it is running in kubernetes container, so permission should not be an issue right

Comment: Why? Kubernetes is not exempt from file permissions. Unless absolutely everything is run as root, that is.

Comment: it is used to work earlier, only since yesterday getting this error.If it is permissions, it should not work before also right?
And using the official image only https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jenkins/
There it defaults to jenkins user.
Even when I try to access the shell of pod and try to run sudo, gets error as sudo command not found.

Comment: Right, then don't try to figure out what's wrong :) Because it used to work. And FYI sudo is not installed by default in most distro containers, so that doesn't seem abnormal to me.

Comment: permissions are there to the jenkins user. Because using the default image only jenkins/jenkins. COuld you please suggest any other steps.

Because changing to root user also not supporting as no sudo command